# Walrasian Equilibrium with

Tags: microeconomics

I have such a question:

In an economy with $ \ge 2  $  consumers, each agent’s utility functions are given as:

$$
(x_1 ,x_2) =max\{2min\{2x_1,x_2\},min\{x_1,4x_2\} \}
$$

The endowments in the economy are given as:
$ (_1 ,_1) = (1+3,2-)$ with  $$ $∈$ $(0,1)$

Find the conditions on $$ which ensure that a Walrasian equilibrium exists for this
economy. How does $$ relate to the size of the set of $$ for which Walrasian
equilibrium is ensured to exist?

I encounter first time with that type of question so I couldnt attempt to solve it.
I appreciate it if you can help.

Comment: Try to find the demand first. You can use the approach posted here: https://qr.ae/pvDf9H

Comment: Thank you for your guidance really  Dear Amit. you save my life literally :)